# Sending an Email asynchronously via ActionMailer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, actionmailer

I'm trying to get an email to send asynchronously via ActionMailer for MVC3/MVC4 for C# ASP.NET.

However I have come across 2 problems:

1. If I attempt to use a Task.Run or Task.Start method using a private function, then the HttpContext becomes null, and the email will not send. This is also the case if I use the inbuilt async delivery method.
2. If I attempt to put async/await on the email sending function, that does not work because the return method is void, and I've been told that you cannot await on void functions.

Here is the code I've used for both scenarios (in both cases, assume e is a Model object):

Scenario 1:

```
Action mailAction = new Action(() => { OnSentEmail(e); });
Task mailTask = new Task(mailAction);
mailTask.Start();

private void OnSentEmail(Model e)
{
    new MailController().SendMail(e).Deliver();
    //HttpContext is null here, so cannot send mail
}

OR

new MailController().SendMail(e).DeliverAsync();
```

Scenario 2:

```
await Task.Run(async() => await new MailController().SendMail(e).Deliver());
```

I'm not very good with async methods yet, but this seemed to be the best I could come up with. I cannot use regular SmtpClient because the emails that need to be sent out are in rich HTML format, so this is why I chose ActionMailer so I can send Emails and style them as though they were views.

What I need is to be able to send the Email asynchronously, either by forcing in a HttpContext (I don't know what information the MailerBase uses from the HttpContext to send the emails), or to be able to async/await it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up coming up with was to create a controller method to send the email, then in my original controller method, make a web request to that controller method, without regarding the response. In the method, the id for the model is sent through to retrieve the correct model from the database in the emailing function. This preserves the HttpContext.

```
string url = baseUrl + "/api/Entry/SendEmail?emailId=" + emailId;
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "GET";
req.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext` is necessary for generation `EmailResult` *That is return value of a controller's `SendMail` method*.

`Deliver()` Method could be called in a separate thread.

```
var verificationEmail = new MailController().SendMail(email, new MailModel());
Task.Run(() => verificationEmail.Deliver());
```